# jQuery append/appendTo and IE6

Tags: jquery, append

Well... IE6 is a bad, bad bugger - yes, but huh, this drove me crazy today.

```
var friendMail = $('.friend-email').html();
$('.friend-mails').children('.right, .left').append(friendMail);
```

The above code works in IE7,8/FF/Safari/Chrome flawlessly, but IE6 fails. However, when I made a [fiddle out of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/7Bk3b/), it did work on IE6 too. Kind of a weird bug, fiddle works, my site doesn't.

Then there is the interesting part...

```
$('.friend-email .mail').clone().appendTo('.friend-mails .left');
```

This code works on all above mentioned browsers + IE6. But I'm kind of confused... What is the difference between these two? (append vs appendTo, I guess...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what kind of elements are you trying to append?

Comment: `<div>` with `<label>`, `<input>` inside of it. See jsFiddle for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `append` and `appendTo` is a matter of ordering. The following two lines are the same:

```
$('.friend-email .mail').clone().appendTo('.friend-mails .left');
$('.friend-mails .left').append($('.friend-email .mail').clone());
```

However, the *real* difference between your two examples is that the first retrieves the HTML as text, and creates new elements out of that text, while the second version uses DOM methods to clone the existing DOM elements, which is more reliable (and typically faster too).